# Get PayPal Hosted Button Code using URL

Tags: python, paypal

I wish to allow users on my site to add PayPal hosted buttons to personalised web pages hosted on it.

Since allowing them to upload the HTML code of the button is not easy to secure against XSS (that is - writing a strict whitelist validation of the HTML format), I'm looking for a way to get the HTML code from PayPal itself using the hosted button ID (which the users will upload, instead of the raw HTML code).

Does anyone know if PayPal cater to this need? If not - do you know of an easy way for me to validate the HTML (preferably in python) as something I can safely load to a customised web page?

Thanks, 
-Lior

Answer (score 1):

I believe that with the button ID is enough. What else you need? With the button ID you can build the whole HTML button code.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="{ID GOES HERE}">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/ES/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Thing is - "buy now" buttons are highly configurable, via the PayPal website you can define a lot of things for the button HTML such as the button language, add different options (with different prices), etc. 

Building the button this way won't allow the user to enjoy these options, right?

Comment: Hi. That is not actually a "buy now", it depends what type of button you selected when you created the button. When you have "_s-xclick" it means "The button that the person clicked was protected from tampering by using encryption, or the button was saved in the merchant's PayPal account.". Almost all essential info is stored in the button. However, you are right about options such language, "os0", "currency_code", etc.

Comment: Please check my other answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PayPal API called "Button Manager API Operations" which will allow you to obtain button information if you have the ID. However, the caller must have the credentials of the account of the hosted button. Here you can find information about it:

[General Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#pps)

You will need specifically the call "BMGetButtonDetails"

[BMGetButtonDetails Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMGetButtonDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: Hold on, this is getting interesting; would PayPal allow me to let my users log in using their PayPal accounts, choose one of their buttons on my site and then send its id and their token so I can query the button HTML code from PayPal? 

If you think this is possible - that would be awesome! Just can't seem to understand what the API is about, it seems to be mostly about better use of a personal PayPal account.

Comment: When using the PayPal API calls you always need your PayPal credentials. In your particular case you will need your users credentials. User can actually create credentials for third-parties (you). With the credentials you can query PayPal about information of hosted buttons. So basically you only need the users API credentials.
Here you can see how to obtain those credentials (API signature):
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/

Comment: Overviewing it, it looks like my users will have to go through hell to log in using PayPal and then view their buttons… with all the certificates and stuff. Correct me if I'm wrong. 

It would just be an easier task to build a parser for the raw HTML code (even though it seemed at first as the harder solution).

Comment: I agree with you. It might be easier to parse the raw html code OR to give the options so users can create the buttons in your site (like PayPal does). Anyway, I was just giving the solutions that PayPal provides for your case.

Comment: And I greatly appreciate it, my friend. If it wasn't clear before. 

Thanks a lot for your insight.